# Upper Unitriangular Matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

Let $U$ be the group of the upper unitriangular matrices $n$-$n$ over the field of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$. I know that $U$ is nilpotent and torsion-free. It is also radicable? How it can be proved in an elementary way?

**Deifnition**

A gorup $G$ is said to be a **radicable** group iff every element of $G$ has an $n$th root in $G$ for all positive numbers $n$.

Comment: I believe you just use the logarithm. log( 1+x) = x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 -+ x^n/n, where that last term is identically zero, since x is nilpotent and n x n.

Comment: I don't know how to write it up nicely, but the idea is $\sqrt[n]{1+x} = \exp( \tfrac1n \log(1+x) )$ is a power series expression for the $n$th root of $1+x$ where $x$ is strictly upper triangular. Since $x^n=0$ (being strictly upper triangular), the power series is actually a finite series, and so converges in any ring in which $n!$ is invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **yes, $U$ is radicable.**

The intuition is that a single matrix acts like a variable that satisfies its minimal polynomial. Any matrix in $U$ has minimal polynomial $(u-1)^N$ for some $N \leq n$. In other words, it behaves much like the $R[x]$-module $R[x]/(x-1)^N$, which are just power series centered at $1$ with at most $N$ terms. Here $R$ is the ring from which we draw the matrix entries, so $R=\mathbb{Q}$, though I'll generally just assume it is commutative, associative, and unital, with a few specific integers being invertible.

### Newton's formula

The explicit formula: if $u \in U$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\tfrac 1m \in R$, then set $$v = \sum_{i=0}^N \binom{ 1/m}{i} (u-1)^i$$ where $(u-1)^N=0$. Here we assume the binomial coefficients $\binom{ 1/m}{i}$ make sense in $R$, for instance if $N!$ is invertible in $R$, for instance, if $R=\mathbb{Q}$.

By certain logical constructions in $\mathbb{Q}[x] \leq \mathbb{R}$ we can use calculus II to see that $v^m = u$ up to a multiple of $(u-1)^N$, but a multiple of $0$ is $0$, so $v^m = u$ exactly.

Maybe someone else can explain it better. Another version is $v=\exp(\tfrac 1m \log(1+(u-1)))$, but this gives basically the same issue. I'm more familiar with this version, where you just use properties of exponentials and logarithms in $\mathbb{Q}[\![x]\!]$.